# Banking Maths, Empty account

Tags: c#, math, banking

So i'm trying to write a banking app and thought after doing modules on processing  a few years ago the maths would be easier than it is. Basically Im trying to distribute the funds proportionately between the two colleagues whenever they make a sale. So instead of half each they get 1/4 and 3/4 of the balance depending on their holdings. I have the maths worked out and a loop to implement the transaction but I have ran out of ideas of how to make c# do the math. I distributed manually but that would only work for a set number and when I am around. Can anybody help? This is more just a proof it can work to get back into coding so any help is appreciated, thanks

```
namespace banking
{
internal class BankAccount
{
    private double Money = 0;
    private String name;

    public BankAccount(double money, string name)
    {
        Money = money;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void AddMoney (double amount)
    {
        //Money = Money + amount;
        Console.WriteLine("Added " + amount + " to the account of " + name);
        Money += amount;
    }
    public void Subtract(double Money)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Taken " + Money + " from the account of " + name);
        this.Money -= Money;
    }
    public void getInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + " has " + Money);
    }
}
}
```

So this works kinda but this is my problem with comments showing my working

```
namespace banking
{

internal class Program
{
    // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
    // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount(money: 10000, name: "Distributer");
        BankAccount bankOne = new BankAccount(money: 25, name: "One");
        BankAccount bankTwo = new BankAccount(money: 75, name: "Two");
        ///Total suppy 1,000,000
        /// distributer wallet balance x (wallet1/total supply)=0.25
        /// distributer wallet balance x (wallet2/total supply)=0.75


        bankAccount.Subtract(Money: 100);
        bankOne.AddMoney(amount: 25);
        bankTwo.AddMoney(amount: 75);

        bankAccount.getInfo();
        bankOne.getInfo();
        bankTwo.getInfo();




 //           if (bankAccount >= 100)
 //         {
 //
 //           /* if condition is true then print the following */
 //         Console.WriteLine("balance is less than 100");
 //           }
 //           else
 //           {
 //               /* if condition is false then print the following */
 //               Console.WriteLine("balance is more than 100 so distributing");
 //           }

        }

     }
 }
```

Comment: Doubles (and floats) are not recommended when handling money.  You should use Decimal.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question so that the community can better help you? Is there a specific error or issue that you are stuck on? Here is a guide on how to properly ask a question that also might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I agree with Neil definitely use decimals here as floating points can do weird things in currency/money situations. Also your code is working, so its not clear what the issue is and your requirement doesn't make sense to me at least. Also it appears they can never go over 100? according the the if statement you commented out. Is that the case?

Comment: You seem to be able to calculate the two factors `f1 = 0.25` and `f2 = 0.75`. So where is the problem? `bankOne.AddMoney(f1 * amount); bankTwo.AddMoney(f2 * amount);`. Also: `if (bankAccount >= 100) Console.WriteLine("balance is less than 100");`, really???

Comment: I'd recommend reading Eric Evan's "Domain Driven Design".  He has a chapter on problems like this.